# CSV file write and read using python

Tags: python

I have a csv named temp.csv where 3 columns

```
Name    Iteration     Value //this temp.csv file
module1   1             10
module2   2             20
module3   3             30
module4   4             40
module1   5             50
module2   6             60
module3   7             70
module4   8             80
module1   9             90
```

now i want a new csv named accumuated.csv like

```
Name    Iteration     Value
module1   1,5,9        150 i.e. 10+50+90
module2   2,6          80 i.e. 20+60
modul13   3,7          100 i.e.  30+70
module4   4,8          120 i.e. 40+80
```

Comment: "What have you tried" comments are now forbidden. But, you know, what have you tried?

Comment: @jamylak http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760

Comment: @user What is the question?

Comment: @user2147857 To extend on the what have you tried, everything is missing from this question. I can see that each iteration goes up through each module by 4 but you didn't even bother to add that to the question. Could you please add to your question: your code so far and what you would like to achieve

Comment: there is a nice module for working with csv files called... csv ?

Comment: downvoting due lack of a real question

Answer (score 3):

You should maintain a dictionary with "Name" as the key. The value can be a list with "Iteration" and "Value".

Traverse through the input csv file and update the dictionary based on the "Name".

**Example code:**

```
with open("111.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print lines

data = {}

for line in lines[1:]:
    print line
    name, iteration, value = line.split()
    print line
    if name not in data:
        data[name] = [[], 0]

    data[name][0].append(iteration)
    data[name][1] += int(value)

print data
```

Now write it back to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a dictionary with names as keys and lists including both the iterations (as a sub-list) and the sums as values, e.g.:

```
d = {}
with open("orig.csv") as f:
    lines = [f.split(',') for f in f.readlines()[1:]
for line in lines:
    if line[0] not in d:
        d[line[0]] = [0,[]]
    d[line[0]][1].append(line[1])
    d[line[0]][0] += line[2]
with open("new.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write("Name,Iteration,Value")
    for mod in d:
        f.write(mod+',"'+','.join(d[mod][1])+'",'+d[mod][0]+'\n')
```

Comment: Hi..its works but in reverse like module4 is inserted first then module3, module2 and module1. how can i reverse this.

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted, so you can't even reliably count on the order being backwards. Try `for mod in sorted(d.keys())`.